# what's wrong with this angular 2 service implementation?

Tags: javascript, angular

The following Angular2 JobService implementation returns the error:

> job.service.ts:26 An error occurred Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}

The `jobsUrl` variable defined in the service returns a json result for a jobs result when submitted directly through a browser address bar. Any idea what the issue might be?

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { JobsResult } from './jobs-result';

@Injectable()
export class JobService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private jobsUrl = 'http://service.dice.com/api/rest/jobsearch/v1/simple.json?text=javascript';
  //private jobsUrl = 'app/jobs';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getJobs(): Promise<JobsResult>{
    return this.http.get(this.jobsUrl)  
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as JobsResult)
               .catch(this.handleError);      
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('getJobs() not working');
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give a real demo of your problem somewhere like https://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: What headers is angular sending?  I notice you're not actually setting the headers in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is undefined, response doesn't have data as key

```
.then(response => response.json() as JobsResult)
```

instead of

```
.then(response => response.json().data as JobsResult)
```